# Prevent creation of Contacts folder in userprofile

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

How can I prevent windows 7 from creating the **contacts** folder in a new user profile. It's not in the default user profile.

Comment: Are you part of a domain?

Comment: Yes. It's in a domain.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this [GPO](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd744697%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#WS_DisableKnownFolders) with the GUID ({56784854-C6CB-462b-8169-88E350ACB882}) of the Contacts folder. This works only for new created profiles.